# Node.js 'socket hang up' and keep-alive

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a very strange error happening.
I am running Node.js version 8.0.0 on Mac OS X Sierra.

I create a very simple http server that basically returns 'ok' to any request after 8 seconds in this example.

I then use the 'request' package to make a request to my http server every 9 seconds, and use the parameter 'forever' to keep the http session alive.

One request out of two works perfectly fine while the other out of two returns a 'socket hang up' error.

Here is the very simple code to reproduce the issue:

```
const http = require('http');
const request = require('request');
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log('request');
  setTimeout(() => {
    res.end('ok');
  }, 8000);
});
server.listen(port);

setInterval(() => {
  request(`http://localhost:${port}/`, {forever: true}, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) return console.log('error', error);
    console.log('done', body);
  });
}, 9000);
```

When I run this code I get the following output on my Macbook Pro :

```
request
done ok
request
error { Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:343:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:435:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1045:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
request
done ok
request
error { Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:343:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:435:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1045:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
request
done ok
request
error { Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:343:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:435:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1045:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

So I get an 'socket hang up' error exactly every other request.

It seems that the error does not seem to appear on an Ubuntu VPS though.

Any ideas as to why this issue is happening ?

Comment: Hi, Are you able to still able to reproduce the issue? I tried the same code in my MacOS Sierra. The requests are completing successfully for me.

Comment: Tried reproducing on both Node v8.2.1 and v6.11.1 using request 2.81.0 and macOS 10.12.6 – could not reproduce it

Comment: I'm still reproducing the issue on Big Sur 11.6 and Node v14.16.0. My test is with simple express server which returns 200 immediately. The server has keepAliveTimeout 5 seconds. I test with the default http module and the sleep between my requests is 5 seconds.